# Entity Framework ignores arithmetic overflow error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, reporting-services

I am calling a stored procedure using the entity framework in my test app:

```
using (CmsEntities context = new CmsEntities())
            {

                try
                {
                    var test = context.TestSPROC().;
                    MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
                }
                catch (EntityException exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                }
            }
```

In my stored procedure all I do is convert an int into a numeric **with the intention** of generating an arithmetic overflow exception. I tried doing this in two ways:

a) Set a variable using the convert function and selecting this variable.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [cms].[TestSPROC]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Test INT 
SET @Test=CONVERT(NUMERIC(3,2),15)
    SELECT @Test AS Test
END
```

b) Performing the convert during select

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [cms].[TestSPROC]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(3,2),15) AS Test
END
```

Both of them throw the arithmetic overflow exception in SQL Server Management Studio, the problem is catching the exception in Visual Studio 2010.

Using method a) The EntityException is caught and can be handled, however using method b) the exception is ignored and the application keeps on running as if there is no problem. So it seems to me as if the Entity Framework is hiding the error in some way.

Comment: Please add store procedure too so get better idea of the question

Comment: Maybe an issue with the VS environment settings or missing a keyword concerning overflow checking? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: When you use method B, what does the message box in your app show you?